# Referencing Django login name from within a model

Tags: python, django, authentication, database-schema

I'll start by saying that my database skills are weak, and it's quite possible I'm just designing this wrong.

I'm working on a Django 1.3 application that would allow customers to log in to view various aspects of their "account".  One of the models is "Customer", and it makes sense to me that I add a field in that model for "username" so that I can show projects, payments etc that belong to each customer.

I've got much of my schema set up but I can't figure out how to make a "username" field that references the django login name.  You average field looks something like

```
projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project')
website = models.URLField()
```

**updates to clarify**
what I think I need is:
username = models.ForeignKey(WhereverDjangoKeepsTheUserModel)

**SOLVED**
I needed 
    `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
and
    `username = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Accepting Jack M's answer because it helped me find the specific piece I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for a [ForeignKey relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

```
projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project')
website = models.URLField()
user = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

Then from within your view:

```
project = Project.objects.all()[0]
username = project.user.username ## Or whatever you want to do with it.
```

To read more about this, check out the "Your First Model" section in [chapter 5](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/) of [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/).

Comment: I get foreign keys, and I've used them elsewhere in the application, my question is about how to get the username data from within the model.

For example, your reply included
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')

but that seems to assume I already have a model that contains the user info.  I'm trying to figure out how to access that data from within models.py so that I can add it, as a foreign key or anything else.  Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding?

Comment: I guess you could sum up my question as "How do i reference Django's built in User model from within my custom model?"  Like

class Customer(models.Model):
username = models.ForeignKey(TheUsernameUsedToLogIntoDjangoPage)

Comment: You wouldn't do that, unless the field you are referencing is the primary key.  You would reference the object and then access the username through that relationship the way I did in my example view code.

Comment: If you absolutely MUST, you could populate that field via a `post_save` signal, but that could be problematic.  You would still need the ForeignKey, and you would have to update that field at each change in a User, or in that Model.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something here, but as soon as I add `user = models.ForeignKey('User')` my models fail to validate, with _main.customer: 'user' has a relation with model User, which has either not been installed or is abstract._.  What I fail to see is where that user data is supposed to be coming from.  Thank you for your patience I'm trying to make this painless.